# Jenkins not returning from console

Tags: jenkins, ant

With ANT build we have automated a Jar creation and we execute the jar in server with ant SSHEXEC task, We have moved the same to CI(Jenkins) environment, Currently everything works fine. But, Jenkins job is not exited as the service is not returning.
Please help me out of this, Below is my code,

```
<target name="tomcat-start">
   <sshexec host="10.0.19.47"
    trust="true"
  username="${server_username}"
  password="${server_password}"
  command="nohup java -jar /home/techteam/TravelSecure-deployments/DTCMWS_TravelSecure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &amp; disown" />
  <echo> Microsite service started successfully. Please wait for service to start running</echo>
  </target>
```

Comment: Remove "amp" and just use &.

Comment: It throws the error 'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference'